# Spinner OnItemClick is not getting called in android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

i have one problem with android spinner onItemClickListener().

i know that onItemClickListener is not working with spinner so i just customize the spinner class and override the setOnItemClickListener() method of spinner class.

following is the code that i have customized....

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MySpinner extends Spinner {

private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public MySpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    super.onClick(dialog, which);

    if (this.onItemClickListener != null) {

        this.onItemClickListener.onItemClick(this, this.getSelectedView(), which, this.getSelectedItemId());

    }

}

@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l) {

    this.onItemClickListener = l;
}

}


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class SpinnerOnItemClickActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private MySpinner spinner;

String[] str_arr = new String[]{"abc", "efg", "hij"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_on_item_click);

    spinner = (MySpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str_arr));

    this.spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_spinner_on_item_click, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    Log.i("Test", "********************Spinner Item Click**************************" + position);
}
}
```

The above code is working perfectly with android version 2.2 and 2.3 but it is not working with android version 4.0 and above.

i have debug the code and found that onClick() method of spinner class is not getting called in android version 4.0.

any help would be appreciable.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For Spinner you have to use `OnItemSelectedListener` because the behaviour of of Spinner is selecting Item from a List of Spinner Items.

`OnItemClickListener` is used for ListView where you have all the List Items and you have to click the items that are in the ListView and listen its action.

Comment: There's a lot of use for onItemClick, because onItemSelected gets fired everytime the spinner is created and that defeats the purpose of informing the programmer when the user explicitly selecting an item.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
     samplespin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.audspinner1);
     samplespin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        edtsample.setText(samplevalues[position]);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        edtsample.setText("");

    }
});

ArrayAdapter sample = new ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            samplevalues);

    sample.setDropDownViewResource(
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    samplespin.setAdapter(sample);
```

Comment: i know the onItemSelected method of spinner class...but i can't use that method in my application...i want itemclick listener of spinner...:(

Answer (score 0):

ok try the following code

```
    list = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, RATINGS));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            selected = RATINGS[arg2];

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```